# Windows Form fade in effect problem VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, project, fadein

I have a problem with the fade effect of the Windows Form.
This form should read the value of a file and store it in a variable and then start a timer that should increase the opacity of the form up to the value read, but it does not happen.

I tried two methods to store the value in a variable, the first:

```
If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(Application.StartupPath & "\Users\" & My.Settings.username & "\opacity.goodsetting") Then
        Try
            Using read As New StreamReader(Application.StartupPath & "\Users\" & My.Settings.username& "\opacity.goodsetting")
                If read.ReadLine = "50" Then
                    varOpacity = 0.5
                ElseIf read.ReadLine = "60" Then
                        varOpacity = 0.6
                ElseIf read.ReadLine = "70" Then
                        varOpacity = 0.7
                ElseIf read.ReadLine = "80" Then
                        varOpacity = 0.8
                ElseIf read.ReadLine = "90" Then
                        varOpacity = 0.9
                ElseIf read.ReadLine = "100" Then
                        varOpacity = 1
                End If
                read.Close()
                End Using
        Catch ex As Exception
            varOpacity = 1
            Me.Opacity = 1
        End Try
End If
Timer2.Start()
```

and the second:

```
Try
    varOpacity = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(Application.StartupPath & "\Users\" & My.Settings.username & "\opacity.goodsetting")
    Me.Opacity = varOpacity / 100
Catch ex As Exception
    varOpacity = 1
    Me.Opacity = 1
End Try
```

but neither method works.

I also leave the effect code:

```
Me.Opacity = Me.Opacity + 0.1
If Me.Opacity = varOpacity Then
    Timer2.Stop()
End If
```

Thanks to everyone.

Comment: What kind of Timer is `timer2`? You should show how that Timer works. Set `Option Strict On`, correct everything  that squiggles and try again. (Use a `System.Windows.Form.Timer`, instanciated explicitly). Also, *it doesn't work* isn't much of a description. Make this description more explicit, too.

Comment: Calling ReadLine() repeatedly is a bug.  Call it just once, store its return value in a variable.  Then check the variable value.

Comment: Do a `Debug.Print `or a `MessageBox.Show` on `Application.StartupPath & "\Users\" & My.Settings.username & "\opacity.goodsetting"` Then check if you really have a file at that location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example of what I think you want...
I've tried to keep it as close to your original example.
For testing purposes, I've put the code in the Form_Load and added a Timer.
Hopefully you can test and change to your own needs.

Form needs to have its `Opacity` set to 0 in designer.
Code will fade in from 0 to value stored in file, else, default to 1.

Code has Imports `System.IO`

```
Private varOpacity As Double

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    'Set the path just once.
    Dim pathOpacityLimit As String = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath & "\Users\" & My.Settings.username, "opacity.goodsetting")
    If File.Exists(pathOpacityLimit) Then
        Try
            Using read As New StreamReader(pathOpacityLimit)
                If Double.TryParse(read.ReadLine, varOpacity) Then
                    'Value parsed - changed to 0.0 > 1.0 so inline with Me.Opacity. Start timer.
                    varOpacity /= 100
                    Timer2.Start()
                Else
                    'Incorrect (not parsed) value in file - set default
                    Me.Opacity = 1
                End If
                read.Close()
            End Using
        Catch ex As Exception
            'Exception - set default
            Me.Opacity = 1
        End Try
    Else
        'File doesn't exist - set default
        Me.Opacity = 1
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Timer2_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer2.Tick
    Me.Opacity += 0.1
    If Me.Opacity < varOpacity Then Exit Sub
    Me.Opacity = varOpacity
    Timer2.Stop()
End Sub
```

I hope this is enough to get you started. You could also have a check of the stored value to see if it falls within the required 0 to 100 range.